# onClick event error : run on 1 node - 0 found

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Trying to run the following test but i keep getting this msg:

Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Here is the test file:

```
 beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<BrowserRouter><Component {...baseProps} /></BrowserRouter>));

it("should test click event on CloseModal method", () => {
 wrapper.find('Component').setState({ 
    showselectWarning: true,
 });
 wrapper.update() 
wrapper.find('#dontshow-testclick').simulate("click");
 expect(wrapper.state().showselectWarning).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Here is the onclick event under Render() Modal

```
 <div className='confirm-entitlement-div'>
              <label>Do not show this message again</label>
              <input type='checkbox' checked={!this.state.showSelectWarning} id='dontshow-testclick' onClick={() => {this.setState({showSelectWarning: !this.state.showSelectWarning})} } />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Modal>
```

I cant figure out the problem . using Jest and enzyme for React js Thank you